# How to get a image file working with parcel.js and vue-loader in WordPress plugin

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader, parceljs

I feel really stuck with this simple thing.

I'm trying to add an `img` element in my Vue template with a static `src`. The component is used in WordPress plugin.

Here is my template (location of the vue file is `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/assets/parcel/src/components/my-component.vue`):

```
<template>
    <div class="some-class">
        <img src="../assets/img.png" alt="">
    </div>
</template>
```

The image file is located in `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/assets/parcel/src/assets/img.png`.

After saving of the component file (and having `npm run watch`) I can see that parcel is adding a new image in the `builds` folder where the compiled js is and from where I'm enqueuing it in WordPress (the js file). But when I open the page in the browser I got only

```
<div class="some-class
   <img src="/img.89b1362f.png" alt="">
</div>
```

My guess is that I'm not doing anything to tell parcelJS that actually this image should has a different url from the default one. But I don't know how to do this - should I edit something from the parcel bulndler js file?